# be Using Biber with Texmaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker, biber

I have been trying to get my bibliography to work in Texmaker for days, searching the internet, etc. and am having no luck. I'm hoping you can help me out.

Here is my test code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[
backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ReferencesMaster.bib}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \parencite{apardian2017study} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{chen2016effects} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I can successfully use Bibtex when I configure Texmaker's Bib(la)tex command and use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, but when I switch it to both back to biber, I get the follow error message:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.11 INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg' INFO - Reading
'test.bcf' INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0
 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ReferencesMaster.bib' for section 0 INFO - 
LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'ReferencesMaster.bib' ERROR -
 BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/sm/k_n34lsd247d8tsz8v72yzs00000gn/T/EBOgoF492O/ReferencesMaster.bib_26499.utf8, line 1, syntax error: found "title", expected
 "=" INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a sample of my bibliography.

```
@article{apardian2017study,
  title={A Study of Effectiveness of Midblock Pedestrian Crossings: Analyzing a Selection of High-Visibility Warning Signs},
  author={Apardian, Bekka and Alam, Bhuiyan Monwar},
  journal={Interdisciplinary Journal of Signage and Wayfinding},
  volume={1},
  number={2},
  pages={26--59},
  year={2017}
}

@article{besag1974spatial,
  title={Spatial interaction and the statistical analysis of lattice systems},
  author={Besag, Julian},
  journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological)},
  pages={192--236},
  year={1974},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{chen2016effects,
  title={Effects of the built environment on automobile-involved pedestrian crash frequency and risk},
  author={Chen, Peng and Zhou, Jiangping},
  journal={Journal of Transport \& Health},
  volume={3},
  number={4},
  pages={448--456},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

This may be a dumb question, but I'm a beginner here... do I need to install Biber? In addition to Texmaker, I also have LaTeXiT, TeX Live Utility, TeXShop, BibDesk, Texstudio, and MiKTeX Console installed. I am running it on a mac.

Comment: Your error is in your `.bib` file. You definitely have `biber` installed because `biber` is producing the error you see. It looks like you have a `.bib` entry that is missing an `=` after the `title` key.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That error must have been corrected. I have no problem typesetting his file.

Comment: I don't see any missing `=` in my file. Would it help if I posted the entire bibliography? I haven't updated since posting.

Comment: you mean you have both tex live and miktex installed?

Comment: It says Tex Live Utility...? I don't ever use it.

Comment: Try deleting all your `.aux` files and make sure you've saved your most recent `.bib` file.

Comment: The question in the title should be answered with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But as Alan mentions and the log message shows, you are already running Biber, so that is not your problem. Biber complains about line 1 of your `.bib` file, but the snippet shown in the question is fine. I suggest you try and cut down (a copy! of) your `.bib` file as much as possible while still reproducing the error and post that here (with "binary search" it should be possible to easily find the culprit, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/)

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above the code shown so far does not reproduce the error in question. If there are no new developments here in due time I will vote to close as *unclear what you are asking* since the error can't be reproduced.

Comment: After searching through, I think the issue was a few minor formatting errors in my bibliography. Thanks for the comments, I was sure it was something more complex since I'm new at this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was caused by other errors not shown in the question. The OP succeeded in resolving the minor issues themselves. The MWE in the question did not reproduce the issue.